# Is it a problem to eat in the succah before Sukkot?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, sukkah, bal-tosif-no-adding

Can someone eat in the Succah before Sukkot, or could it be a problem of *bal tosif*?

Does it make a difference if it's like, an hour before candle lighting, the morning of erev chag, or a week before?

Comment: From what I have been told, it seems this is no different from eating in a succah on Simchas Torah. Succos is over, you don't say the blessings, but there is nothing to stop you from eating outside on a nice day.

Comment: @Dennis There is a whole Siman in Shulchan Arukh about how to eat in the Sukkah on Simchat Torah in a Kosher way in case of necessity. It's not that simple.

Comment: I would think we shouldn't do so in order to make a distinction between before the yontoff and the actual yontoff. another time we make this distinction is when we don't blow shofar the day before rosh hashana. even though throughout the month there is a minhag to blow the shofar we don't the day before in order to show the difference between minhag and mitzvah